# intermediate javascript: wrapper function to ajax request executes primary function later

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, normally I have an ajax request wrapper function where I pass the $data and `$sucessFunctionA` and execute the `$.ajax` request.

But what I want to do is make another function: `$successFunctionB` which takes `$sucessFunctionA` as a parameter.

So I pass $data and `$successFunctionB` to the `$.ajax` request.

Supposing it is a successful result. `$successFunctionB` executes. `$successFunctionB` checks the data result for a value. If it's a certain value, then it will execute `$successFunctionA`.
What may be confusing me is that the sucessFunction to the ajax request can only have one parameter as input which is the result data.

Here is the broken code of what i'm trying to do

```
function ajaxCall($data,$successFunctionA) 
{

var $successFunctionB = function($data,$successFunctionA)
{
                data = jQuery.parseJSON($data);
                if(data.result=='good')
                {
                    $successFunctionA(data);
                }
}

$.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:'server.php',
        datatype:'json',
        data:$data,
        success:$successFunctionB,
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass $successFunctionA to $successFunctionB - function B will have access to function A because in javascript, functions are **closures**. So the code just looks like this:

```
function ajaxCall($data,$successFunctionA)
{
    var $successFunctionB = function($data)
    {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON($data);

        if(data.result=='good')
        {
            $successFunctionA(data);
        }
    };

    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'POST',
        url:'server.php',
        datatype:'json',
        data:$data,
        success:$successFunctionB,
    });
}
```

This is one of the most important concepts in js, so if you're not familiar with closures I'd suggest reading up on them: http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.6 or greater, `$.proxy` can apply partial parameters:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type:'POST',
    url:'server.php',
    datatype:'json',
    data:$data,
    success:$.proxy($successFunctionB, this, $successFunctionA)
});
```

The first parameter is the function to execute, the second is the context of the `this` pointer.  Any subsequent parameters will be passed to the `$successFunctionB` function.  Finally, the `$.ajax` call will append its own data as the last parameter, so you should reorder them like this:

```
var $successFunctionB = function($successFunctionA, $data)
```